# The disjoint set in TAOCP

Tags: algorithm, taocp

I want to know if Donald Knuth has covered the disjoint set in his great book ? If so, which chapter is it?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He mentions disjoint set forests, more specifically the associated union-find algorithm, in *Vol 1: Fundamental Algorithms*, page 354.